# Where can the __bytes__ method be found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The official documentation says:

> `object.__bytes__(self)`
>
> Called by `bytes` to compute a byte-string
>   representation of an object. This should return a `bytes` object.

But when I do `dir(object)` or `dir(bytes)` or `dir(bytearray)`, the `__bytes__` method does not show up. So where can it be found?

Comment: Well that's reasonable isn't it: `bytes` is a method that converts *to* bytes, so it is added to objects that convert to `bytes`, not in `bytes` itself.

Comment: Can you give me an example of an object to which it is added?

Comment: How about: `bytes([1,2,3])`.  Also see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-bytes)

Comment: `bytes([1, 2, 3])` does not have a `__bytes__` method.

Comment: I did a search in Python 3 library files and found just few of them. `email.message.Message`, `pathlib.PurePath`, `wsgi.headers.Headers`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bytes doesn't have \_\_bytes\_\_ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236655/bytes-doesnt-have-bytes-method)

Answer (score 4):

[PEP 428](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428)'s `pathlib` (since Python 3.4) may be the most common use of `bytes`.

> The string representation of a path is the raw filesystem path itself (in native form, e.g. with backslashes under Windows), which you can pass to any function taking a file path as a string:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> p = PurePath('/etc')
> >>> str(p)
> '/etc'
> ```
>
> Similarly, calling bytes on a path gives the raw filesystem path as a bytes object, as encoded by os.fsencode():
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> bytes(p)
> b'/etc'
> ```

These conversions happen through `pathlib.__str__()` and `pathlib.__bytes__()` magic methods.

Comment: I guess that if a `__bytes__` method is defined for a custom object, then the `bytes` builtin function will return a bytes representation of the object. The method is not available as such in any builtin type.

Answer (score 2):

### Where it can be found?

[Starting in 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#other-cpython-implementation-changes), the `bytes` type itself implements `__bytes__`. No other built-in types do:

```
>>> [k for k, v in vars(__builtins__).items() if k != 'bytes' and hasattr(v, '__bytes__')]
[]
```

Here are the only standard library types that appear to implement it (based on [searching the GitHub repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=__bytes__) and filtering out test and documentation results manually - a process which also verifies that other builtin types don't implement it):

- [`pathlib.PurePath`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1ca315538f2f9da6c7b86c4c46e76d454c1ec4b9/Lib/pathlib.py#L346) (and its subclasses)
- [`email.message.Message`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6746135b0722a5359ce6346554c847afba603b5a/Lib/email/message.py#L191) (and its subclasses)
- [`wsgiref.headers.Headers`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/wsgiref/headers.py#L141)
- [`typing.SupportsBytes`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58d2b30c012c3a9fe5ab747ae47c96af09e0fd15/Lib/typing.py#L2815), although of course this is only an ABC intended for type checking

Finally, [`weakref.proxy`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/11a2c6ce516b24b2435cb627742a6c4df92d411c/Objects/weakrefobject.c#L651) will fake having a `__bytes__` if (and only if) the proxied object has it.

### Why doesn't it show up normally?

Consider the quote in context: this is listed in the ["Special method names" section of the documentation for Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

The introduction tells us:

> A class can implement certain operations that are invoked by special syntax (such as arithmetic operations or subscripting and slicing) by defining methods with special names. This is Python’s approach to *operator overloading*, allowing classes to define their own behavior with respect to language operators. For instance, if a class defines a method named `__getitem__()`, and `x` is an instance of this class, then `x[i]` is roughly equivalent to `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)`. Except where mentioned, attempts to execute an operation raise an exception when no appropriate method is defined (typically `AttributeError` or `TypeError`).

The operative word here is "can". Despite that the methods are listed as `object.__whatever__`, this is *not* intended to assert that the `object` type - or any other type in particular - actually implements the method. It is *only* describing the semantics *if* some type implements the method - i.e., how it will be used by standard machinery, when detected.

For example, the documentation also lists comparison dunders, like `__lt__`, but `object` doesn't implement those either:

```
>>> object() < object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'object' and 'object'
```

Although of course other types can and do implement them.

Similarly, `object` doesn't provide `__bytes__`:

```
>>> bytes(object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot convert 'object' object to bytes
```

However, defining `__bytes__` on a type *will* enable coercion to bytes:

```
>>> class Example:
...     def __bytes__(self):
...         return b'Test'
... 
>>> bytes(Example())
b'Test'
```