# bytes doesn't have __bytes__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x

So... I have code more or less along these lines:

```
class Foo(bytes):
    def __bytes__(self):
        return b'prefix' + super().__bytes__()
```

But unique taste for consistency of Python core developers gets in my way, and this attempt fails miserably.

Looking at methods defined on `bytes` class, I see no way to reproduce its default printing behavior in subclasses.

Or maybe there is a way?

Comment: `super.__bytes__()`? You mean `super().__bytes__()`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell regardless of number and position of underscores, there isn't a method in the superclass that contains substring `bytes`.

Comment: Sure, but I was correcting the lack of parenthesis following `super`.

Comment: What is the actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FHTMitchell yes, that's a typo. I'll fix that. In original code, there are parenthesis

Comment: Here's the fix: `return b'prefix' + self`.  If you are outside of the subclass of `bytes`, then you should use `bytes(object)` instead which works on `bytes` too.

Comment: You're right, it's weird that `bytes` doesn't define `__bytes__`. [`__bytes__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bytes__) is definitely one of the dunder protocols. I'd raise a [bpo](https://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: A `bytes` object doesn't need to implement `__bytes__`, as `bytes` already knows how to deal with an argument of type `bytes`.

Comment: @chepner I mean, maybe, but `'hello'.__str__()` and `(3.14).__float__()` both compile. I would always expect that instead of calling `bytes(obj)` I can call `obj.__bytes__()`.

Comment: So? If you are explicitly calling a dunder method, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta It actually works! Although it shouldn't :D Consistency is the word Python core devs certainly hadn't been introduced to yet.  I wouldn't even try that expecting to get a stack overflow if I do this.

Comment: Why it shouldn't? you inherited from `bytes`, and `bytes` does define `__add__`...

Comment: @chepner That's not true at all. Otherwise subclassing inbuilt types would be impossible. Dunder methods are part of python's explicit public api.

Comment: @chepner. There are clear rules as to *how* to call dunder methods properly, and how to define them properly. I think that that is because they are intended to be used explicitly in many cases.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta because `__add__` *must* defer printing to `__bytes__`, otherwise it is broken.

Comment: "this attempt fails miserably". How exactly? Python's error messages are generally quite useful if you take the time to understand them.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I'm not sure what this has to do with subclassing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist no, not generally, but in this case the reason is obvious, and is in the question's title: missing method.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What rules are you talking about that don't apply to methods in general?

Comment: For that matter, I am unable to reproduce the error. The code that's actually shown here does not raise an error in my interpreter. Perhaps you are missing how you called it in an inappropriate manner?

Comment: @chepner. For example that dunder lookup is only done on the class, even if a dunder method is defined on an instance. I'd say that's something that does not apply to regular methods.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That doesn't suggest a case when it should be called explicitly; it suggests that you can't override a dunder method on a per-object basis.

Comment: @wvxvw Are you sure you don't want to override `__new__` instead?

Comment: @chepner If you never call dunder methods, you must never subclass. I'm always writing `super().__init__()` and `super().__new__(cls, *args)`.

Comment: @chepner. Given some of the stuff I do with properties, I find `object.__setattr__` or `super().__setattr__()` to be useful sometimes.

Comment: OK, mea culpa. But *aside* from overriding an ancestor's implementation... :)

Comment: @chepner. Fair enough. I never override the dunder methods unless I *really* need to :) Even then, it's probably code smell that I justify by telling myself that "I know what I'm doing".

Comment: It seems like you think that every python method is virtual. This is not the case for types directly implemented in C (such as built-ins). These types need to explicitly implement the method as "virtual", but a lot of them do not do this for performance reasons.  Also, you'll find that your subclass is broken... try to slice it for example. Or add it to something. You easily lose your custom class. Subclassing built-ins, IMHO, makes sense only if you go all the way and basically wrap every single method. Other uses are "a hack".

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta that's an interesting info. But, yes, I'd expect all methods of built-in classes to be virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to sum up the comments, the answer is as below (I'm surprised you tried the harder method first):

```
class Foo(bytes):
    def __bytes__(self):
        return b'prefix' + self
```

I think `bytes` not implementing `__bytes__()` is a bit weird though, and I would raise that as an issue with the python dev team.

Comment: In hindsight it seems obvious that you don't need to have `__bytes__` on `bytes` to get a `bytes`, but `str` has `__str__`, so it is indeed a bit misleading. Also, for a second there I was expecting to get a stack overflow :)

Comment: Close, but not 100%. Now imagine having to use this in `super(bytes, Foo)` context... `super(bytes, Foo).__bytes__()` is undefined, but `super(bytes, Foo)` is not a kind of `bytes`, it's a special `super` object...

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.11, the code shown in the question works as-is.

```
>>> class Foo(bytes):
...     def __bytes__(self):
...         return b'prefix' + super().__bytes__()
... 
>>> bytes(Foo(b' hello'))
b'prefix hello'
```

You can find this mentioned in the CPython [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#other-cpython-implementation-changes):

> The special methods `__complex__()` for `complex` and `__bytes__()` for `bytes` are implemented to support the `typing.SupportsComplex` and `typing.SupportsBytes` protocols. (Contributed by Mark Dickinson and Donghee Na in [bpo-24234](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/68422).)